# Is it possible to share a node js source code with multiple EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, node.js

I have a small fleet of EC2 servers that all run the same nodejs app. Deploying an update is painful: create an new AMI, terminate old instances, launch new instances.

Is it possible to centralize the node js source code, and update it at a single place for all EC2 instances ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are probably many ways to do it.

One might be to put the code on S3 and have a script download the latest source code when the EC2 instance boots.

[EC2 startup scripts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

[S3 copy command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).

Another would be to store the source code on [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) and mount it on each server.

Then you'll just need to automate updates and such. I haven't worked out how to automate OS updates, because I've never needed to, but I know there's support for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to activate a new EC2 instance and use it as a dedicated NFS Server. That's a sort of DIY EFS.
Unfortunately Amazon Elastic File System performance are bound to the filesystem size and you don't get anything good until your filesystem reaches a certain size. Unfortunately EFS is quite expensive when compared to EBS or S3. This way a EC2 dedicated NFS server could be less expensive.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I guess it depends on requirements and file count / size. The operating systems will cache the files after first access as well. For a small codebase EFS is probably negligible price and acceptable performance given caching. An EC2 instance needs to be managed, backed up, etc. Also I wonder if the code could be changed to bootstrap itself from S3.